# Cholesterol levels that follow Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, normal-distribution

Let cholesterol levels of a population be described by a normal distribution $X \sim N(μ=250, σ = 50), \quad P_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(x-250)^2}{2 \times 50^{2}}}$

I am asked to compute (a) $P_X(200 \leq x \leq 260)$ and (b) compute $c$ such that $10\%$ of the population has cholesterol higher than $c$.

My try is: a) $P_X(\frac{200-250}{50} < \frac{x - 250}{50} < \frac{260-250}{50}) = P_X(-1 < \frac{x - 250}{50} < \frac{1}{5}) = \Phi(\frac{1}{5})- \Phi(-1) =\Phi(\frac{1}{5})+ \Phi(1) -1 = 0.53 + 0.84 - 1 = 0.38$

b) $P(x > c) = 0.1 \rightarrow P(\frac{x-250}{50} > \frac{c-250}{50})=0.1 \rightarrow 1 - \Phi(\frac{c-250}{50})= 0.1 \rightarrow \Phi(\frac{c-250}{50}) = 0.9$ and using a statistical array I found that that's true for $z = 1.3$ so $\frac{c-250}{50}=1.3 \rightarrow c = 265$

Is my thinking correct, especially for (b)? Thanks =)

Comment: Btw, the pdf of the normal distribution has the standard deviation at the denominator $P_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\cdot\color{red}{50}}e^{\frac{-(x-250)^2}{2 \times 50^{2}}}$

Answer (score 1):

Usually I use more decimal places. For the first part you can use a regular table like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table). It can be read off that $\Phi\left(\frac15\right)=0.57926, \Phi\left(1\right)=0.84134$. Thus the desired result is $0.57926+0.84134-1\approx 0.42$

If we use a the table above we find that $\Phi(0.9)=1.28$. Thus the equation becomes $1.28=\frac{c-250}{50}$. Then something went wrong at your next steps. Multiplying the equation by $50$

$$1.28\cdot 50=c-250$$

$$64=c-250\Rightarrow c=314$$